# is there any SCIM2 compliance test utility available

Tags: scim2

is there any SCIM2 compliance test utility available?

Basically I want to test SCIM2 server functionality whether it satisfy the standards of SCIM2 protocol and schema as defined at

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a working (without bugs) utility in github.

so I wrote one here.

https://github.com/suvera/scim2-compliance-test-utility